# PostCreateView returning Page Error 404 raised by PostDetailView

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I am trying add a `CreateView` in my Django project but I am getting a Page 404 Error raised by `PostDetailView` for some reason I don't undertand why. I am assuming it is because of the url pattern but I have revised it several times but still stuck.

Here is the full error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/score/new_design/
Raised by:  score.views.PostDetailView
```

Here is the Models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    design = models.ImageField(blank=False, null=True, upload_to=upload_design_to)
```

Here is the view.py

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'design']  
    success_url = '/'
    template_name = 'score/post_form.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    success_message = "Your Post has been submitted"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.designer = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Here is the urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='score'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('new_design/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
```

Here is the link to the create view:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'score:post-create' %}">New Post</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try moving your create url above the detail like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
     path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='score'),
     path('new_design/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
     path('<slug:slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
```

This allows the createview to be found first. Or you try editing the detail url like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='score'),
    path('detail/<slug:slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('new_design/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
```

The problem is that since the detailview appears first it is searching for a valid slug to match but errors out since it can't find it